# Teradata multiple connections INSERT deadlock

Tags: java, teradata

I create multiple connections and make batch inserts into myTable simultaneously (multi threading)

```
insertString = "INSERT INTO ... + values + ") "; 
insertTable.addBatch(insertString); 
insertTable.executeBatch();
insertTable.clearBatch();
```

Sometime it works fine, however in other cases it hangs. I understand this is because I am inserting      into the same table  so it gets locked .

**How can I write an `INSERT` statement such that it does not lock the table?**

Are there any special `transaction start . .`   commands that can prevent the table from being locked ? In addition, I am curious why it works fine sometimes  ?

PS: the maximum number of connections that I used was 1024 (worked perfect sometimes)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1024 session is totally insane. Your DBA should block your user for that.

You probably get blocked sessions when you load multiple rows with the same PI.

Single-row INSERTs are the slowest way to load data. A single session with a batch size of a few 1000 will outperform dozens of single-row sessions (but then only use one session).

Or switch to JDBC FastLoad if the target table is empty.

Check
http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/speed-up-your-jdbcodbc-applications

Is this a staging table?

Comment: Thank you. I cannot switch to Fastload, because it sucks. It needs super clean data and a lot of other restrictions. Actually, I am using  `batch`. Each connection uploads a `batch` of 800 rows, so in total I submit 1024*800 rows simultaneously. It used to work ! I wrote my code in a special way , so that even if some connection is blocked, all other connections will still run . Blocked sessions are not an issue. My issue is the locked table

Comment: Blocked session are an issue. When you run multiple sessions with `batch` you will easily end in deadlocks if there are multiple rows with the same RowHash. And there's no way to lock a table when you use multiple session (unless you want to write your own loading tool using the FastLoad/MLoad protocol in CLI). Did you ever check how long it takes to logon 1024 sessions? If this is a staging table you could switch to a NO PRIMARY INDEX table to get a faster load, but never use more than 1 to 2 sessions per node. And why should JDBC FastLoad need cleaner data than your approach?

Comment: This is a staging table, no primary index. It takes less than a minute to logon to 1024 sessions. There are two reasons I am not using FastLoad: 1) `too many load unload ERROR`, and I presume there is nothing I can do with it, can I ? 2) Sometimes I upload notes, which include commas and special untranslatable characters, so Fastload usually fails

Comment: The FastLoad protocol can't logon more sessions than nodes, but all the data you can currently load should be loadable with JDBC FastLoad, too. Neither commas nor untranslatable characters are treated differently when using prepared SQL.